# Items in grid don't resize in response to animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-grid

I have a grid of four squares and I want the other squares to shrink responsively when one expands on hover. They do respond, but only after the transition is complete for the expanding square. Why do they wait until the animation is complete to resize? Is it possible to do this so they respond in real-time to the expanding square?

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    gap: 10px;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.square {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.square:hover {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
    <body>
      <main>
        <div class="square" id="one"></div>
        <div class="square" id="two"></div>
        <div class="square" id="three"></div>
        <div class="square" id="four"></div>
      </main>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [did something similar](https://twitter.com/ChallengesCss/status/1545367863250264075) (related article for full detail: https://css-tricks.com/zooming-images-in-a-grid-layout/)

```css
.gallery {
  --s: 150px; /* control the size */
  --g: 10px;  /* control the gap */
  --f: 1;     /* control the scale factor */
  
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--g);
  width: calc(2*var(--s) + var(--g));
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
}

.gallery > img {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .35s linear;
}

.gallery img:hover{
  width:  calc(var(--s)*var(--f));
  height: calc(var(--s)*var(--f));
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: #60c4ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1028/300/300" alt="a forest after an apocalypse">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/15/300/300" alt="a waterfall and many rocks">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1040/300/300" alt="a house on a mountain">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/106/300/300" alt="sime pink flowers">
</div>
```

It works with divs as well:

```css
.gallery {
  --s: 150px; /* control the size */
  --g: 10px;  /* control the gap */
  --f: 1;     /* control the scale factor */
  
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--g);
  width: calc(2*var(--s) + var(--g));
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
}

.gallery > div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: purple;
  transition: .35s linear;
}

.gallery div:hover{
  width:  calc(var(--s)*var(--f));
  height: calc(var(--s)*var(--f));
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: #60c4ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The article will go live this monday so I will add then

Comment: Neat, this works and I look forward to the article, thank you!

Comment: @jdotwav here is the article: https://css-tricks.com/zooming-images-in-a-grid-layout/

Comment: What amazing timing - I love the article thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `height` and `width` on `:hover` try using `padding` instead. Also, the `transition` should be on the non-hovered state of the element that is being animated only.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.square {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.square:hover {
  padding: 75px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="square" id="one"></div>
    <div class="square" id="two"></div>
    <div class="square" id="three"></div>
    <div class="square" id="four"></div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: That helps the transitions, but for my use case I won't want all that padding around the content inside the square!